# Relational Model: Multiple, overlapping functional dependencies

Tags: relational-database, functional-dependencies

Let's consider the following relation which models the customers somewhere

```
R1 = (customer_num, birth_city, living_city, birth_city_location, living_city_location)
```

where **birth_city** is the city that customer was born in while **living_city** is the city where the customer lives in. Additionally we consider that **one city value determines one location value**.

and let's consider we have the following list of functional dependencies:

```
customer_num --> birth_city
customer_num --> living_city

birth_city --> birth_city_location
living_city --> living_city_location
```

A best decomposition to achieve normal forms will be:

```
(customer_num, birth_city, living_city)
(birth_city, birth_city_location)
(living_city, living_city_location)
```

This means creating two relations for the city.

Indeed, I think that one relation is enough because if we know city we know its location and these two relations mean data redundancy. But if we consider birth_city = living_city in the basic relation we will lose the semantic that birth_city may be different from living_city for each customer.

Considering two relations for city and location is not fair, because their values may overlap and if we decide to change some city's location of the **birth_city** values and this city exists in the **living_city** values, then we leave the DB in an inconsistent state.

I can rephrase the question more generally:

```
R = (A, X1, X2, Y1, Y2)
```

where

```
A --> X1
A --> X2

X1 --> Y1
X2 --> Y2
```

and we have a special situation that is:

```
if t1[X1] = t2[X2] then t1[Y1] = t2[Y2]
```

How to model the relation?

Comment: Normalization is based on semantics--on what the data means? What does "city_location" mean? A latitude/longitude in the middle of the city? A geographic region? Something else?

Comment: Well, let's consider it latitude/longitude. Please note that this is just an example to show my general case despite how much it is accurate, please consider to the general case at the end of my question.

Comment: In that case, the FDs `living_city_location->living_city`, and `birth_city_location->birth_city` also hold.

Answer (score 1):

Although your model does follow the **Principle of Full Normalization** it does not follow the **Principle of Orthogonal Design** i.e. you have two relations that have overlapping meanings.

If you were to follow this principle the relations would be:

Customers (customer_num, birth_city, living_city)
Cities(city, city_location)

such that:

ρ<sub>city/birth_city</sub>(∏<sub>birth_city</sub>(Customers)) ⊆ ∏<sub>city</sub>(Cities)
ρ<sub>city/living_city</sub>(∏<sub>living_city</sub>(Customers)) ⊆ ∏<sub>city</sub>(Cities)

where

∏: Projection
ρ: Rename

I would note there is not agreement about the precise definition of Orthogonal Design.

Comment: I understand that, but how can you express it in relational algebra? I mean exactly that part: birth_city and living_city refer to the city?

Comment: @MedianHilal added relational algebra for referential integrity.

Comment: OK, that seems clear, but it cannot be expressed as functional dependencies. Can it?

Comment: No. A functional dependency is a constraint between attributes in the same relation; this is a description of a constraint between attributes in different relations.